# Find the inradius in a tangential quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In this tangential quadrilateral $AD+BC=22$, $AB=9$, $CF=8$ and $F$ is a tangent point. Find the inradius $r$.

[image]

Here is my attemps:

[image]

Using Pitot's theorem I found that $x+y=9$. Also, using the area formula for tangential quadrilateral i get that:
$$
A=22\cdot r
$$
Also, using the inradius formula in terms of the tangent segments I found that:
$$
r^2=\frac{360+13\cdot x\cdot y}{22}
$$

I draw the problem in AutoCAD and get that $x\approx 3.44836392$ and $y \approx 5.55163608$. So $r \approx 5.26080188$.

I wonder if it is possible to find a natural expression for $r$. I don't know what property should I use.

Many thanks if you can help me.

Comment: You're right. I just realized there is a missing condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though evident from the diagram, the AB || CD is not explicitly specified. Assume such to match the height

$$EG^2=(2r)^2= (x+8)^2-(x-8)^2 = (y+5)^2 - (y-5)^2\tag1$$

which leads to $8x=5y$ and, along with $x+y=9$, to get $x=\frac{45}{13}$ and $y=\frac {72}{13}$. Then, from (1), the inradius is

$$r= 3\sqrt{\frac{40}{13}}$$

Comment: That's right. I see the problem is missing a condition. With AB || CD, we can solve as you have done. I think you're answer is quite right along with the parallel condition.

Comment: @PaúlAguilar - yeah. Otherwise, the problem is not well defined

Answer (score 1):

The problem as stated has infinite number of solutions, since  $x $ can take on any value between $0$ and $9$. Therefore, as follows from your formula, $r^2$ can take on any value in the range:
$$\frac {360}{22}<r^2\le \frac {360+13\cdot\frac {81}4}{22}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, the inequality helps me alot to find a necessary condition to the problem to be solved.